# How to set a value to a control of a dynamic form by index?

Tags: angular

I try to set the value to a control of a dynamic form by index

The dynamic form looks like this

```
  profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: [''],
    address: this.formBuilder.group({
      street: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      zip: [''],
    }),
    aliases: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control('')]),
  });
```

I create a getter to easy access to the aliases in the form array instance

```
  get aliases(): FormArray {
    return this.profileForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
  }
```

I try to set the value to the first Form array control as follows

```
  setInitialValue(): void {
    this.aliases.at(0).setValue('Nancy');
  }
```

The above fails silently.

What is the correct way to set a value to a control within a Form array by index?

Answer (score 1):

```
let formArr = <FormArray>this.profileForm.controls['aliases'];
formArr.controls[i].setValue('Nancy');
```

this is work for me.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I keep the same behavior. The value is not assigned, no message in the console

Comment: I just discovered the reason it doesn't work. Again, thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

I managed to identify my mistake. In the following template

```
<div *ngFor="let alias of aliases.controls; index as i">
  <label>
    Alias
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="i" />
  </label>
</div>
```

For `<input type="text" [formControlName]="i" />` I was using `[formControl]="i"` using `[formControlName]="i"` solve the problem